# Log4net Configuration Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

Had something weird start happening to me today. I have an asp.net mvc app with log4net setup and everything had been working fine. Something must have changed somewhere and now nothing is getting logged (no log file is being created).

Here's my global.asax.cx

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Here's my configuration in my web.config:

```xml
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\logs\api\ApiLog.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

For some reason the `c:\logs\api\apilog.txt` file never gets created. However, if I change my `application_start` method to this it works fine:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("DirectPathToMy\web.config"));
```

Any ideas why calling `Configure()` is not finding the configuration in my web.config by default?

Comment: Are you sure that the `<log4net>` section is defined in your root `~/web.config` file and not the one in `~/Views/web.config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why your approach don't work but the issue is that you need to make sure it is activated in your project.

I usually put this as an assembly level reference in my AssemblyInfo.cs under /Properties:

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]

Reference:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "activated". I call in from my Application_Startup method. Is that not enough? All seems to have worked before.

Comment: That works...but why doesn't calling it from application_start work?